# Table not updated when user logout

Tags: php, mysql

What is the proper way to indicate in your db when a user is logout of an application.

```
session::start();
$username = session::check()["username"];
$link->query("UPDATE admin SET isOnline = 0 WHERE username = '".$username."'");
session::destroy();
exit;
```

This is my current implementation.

Comment: WHere are you executing the query?

Comment: What do you mean by "where"?

Comment: You have a comma before WHERE clause. I've never seen that so I think that could cause a syntax issue.

Comment: @TurtleTread, tnk you. I would try that.

Comment: You're already using an API that supports **prepared statements**, you should utilize parameterized queries with placeholders (prepared statements) to protect your database against [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)!
 Get started with [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare).

Comment: @Qirel, you could have pointed that out, instead of downvoting it, but tnks anyways.

Comment: It's not my downvote.. I voted to close, yes - but that's not a downvote ;-) And I did point out the error in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit:

```
$link->query("UPDATE admin SET isOnline = 0 WHERE username ='".$username."'");
```

Comment: you are both right. I was thinking that he use prepared statement,I checked the question agian and saw that he have unessery comma, edit my answer. thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used:

```
$query = "UPDATE Logins SET logouttime='$logouttime' WHERE Email='$Email' AND 
            fromproxy='$pipaddress' AND fromip='$ipaddress'";
unset($_SESSION);
```